# How to tell which installation guide is legit?

Tags: software-installation

There are many guides on the internet on installation of all sorts of programs under Linux. Some require installation of other programs as part of the installation process. Often the steps described in the guides involve commands starting with sudo. How can we tell which is legit and which could lead to installation of doggy programs?

Comment: The problem is http/https does not crawl itself to find obsolete and inaccurate content and issue warning notices to the content authors.

Comment: I disagree with those who think this question is too opinion-based. I think a good answer to this question could cover the trade-offs between getting software from "the Internet" and from curated sources such as the apt repositories and software center. Guides that focus on software installation from these trusted sources are more likely to be legit.

Comment: As you gain more Linux experience, you'll gain more knowledge of what various install and sudo commands do. Golden rule... DO NOT use any terminal commands, or scripts, unless you know specifically what they're going to do. Period. Use the `man` pages to learn about commands.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best course of action is to pull up your boot-straps, run the installation program and post any questions here if you have a problem.

If you are concerned about a specific program / app / snap then post a question here. Hopefully those familiar with it will post an answer. At the very least some helpful souls will find some links of interest and post them as comments.

Asking for a list of all "doggy" programs is subjective. What is more practical is a list of programs that don't work in certain environments which might be applicable to some and irrelevant to others.

Comment: Thanks. I installed Tuxboot yesterday. Not only the program didn’t work it also modified the list of boot entries in my new Thinkpad ‘s BIOS.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are talking about. Is it a grub boot modifier like TuxKiller2 here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/223255/adding-a-grub2-background-image-and-custom-font/1071418#1071418

Comment: I mean this: https://clonezilla.org/liveusb.php#linux-method-a

Comment: I wanted to install clonezilla but I need to install Tuxboot first.

Comment: I don't think that has much to do with Ubuntu and can't see any reason for using it.

Comment: I asked for recommendation on cloning software. Some suggested clonezilla. Then that site mentioned installation of Tuxboot. After I launched that program, a gray window showed up. Nothing else. So I removed it.

Comment: Clonezilla is mostly used from a live session. Clonezilla has its own bootable CD/USB images.

Comment: In https://itsfoss.com/things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu-18-04/ , in Suggestion 2 the author suggested enabling additional repositories (main, universe, restricted, multiverse, canonical partners) for more software. In Suggestion 7, he suggested installing flatpak using sudo and its plugin to gain access to more programs. Are programs from these sites and also from Ubuntu Software guaranteed to be legit and without spyware, virus? What canonical partners should I enter?

Comment: Is it safe to do things described in this video to modify the GUI of the system? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AHzGYG2XvMI&vl=en